# Communication between Pico and PC over USB with Circuit Python

Tags: python, pi-pico

How do i send text/json or bytes data over USB cable from my PC to Raspberry Pi Pico **using Circuit Python**. I tried to do that using a text file and then editing it from PC but it was taking over 1 second to read the file and light up a LED so i just want a quicker way if it's even possible.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Your question can be divided into two parts: (1) PC sending bytes to Pico through a PC UART 3V3 TTL serial adapter, using C/Python program, or terminal emulatior, such as RealTerm. (2) Pico receiving bytes from PC through Pico's on board UART (uart0 or uart1), using MicroPython.  (1) and (2) are pretty standard and simple.  (4) If you don't want to use any USB terminal emulator, then you can write a program in C or python to read/write PC's serial COM ports on its mother board or at the back of the PC chassis.